# Example Facebook Application using TurboGears -- pyFacebook

Tags: python, facebook, turbogears

I have a TurboGears application I'd like to run through Facebook, and am looking for an example TurboGears project using pyFacebook or minifb.py.  pyFacebook is Django-centric, and I can probably figure it out, but this is, after all, the lazy web.

Answer (score 3):

Why is pyFacebook django centric?  Looks like it works perfectly fine with all kinds of WSGI apps or Python applications in general.  No need to use Django.

Answer (score 1):

pyFacebook is Django-centric because it includes a Django example.  I did not intend to irk, but am merely looking for a TurboGears example using pyFacebook.